# Browser caching of images served by Grails

Tags: grails, caching

I have a controller action which reads an image from the database and serves it to the client:

```
def profilePicture() {
    def profilePicture = ProfilePicture.get(1)
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=1.png")
    response.contentType = "PNG"
    response.outputStream << profilePicture.profilePicture
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

Every time the client requests the image, the server serves the whole image with status `200`. What can I do to instruct the client that this content can be cached?

I have already tried `response.setHeader("Expires", "...")` with a date in the future but this didn't help (I'm guessing this is only part of the story as the server is not returning `304`).

Comment: I'm not 100% knowledgeable in this subject but it seems that the client is somewhat important as well, is it just an `img` tag or are you explicitly calling the controller?

Comment: It is just an `img` tag.

Comment: change tags, it is not grails side work

Comment: try this http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/

Comment: Also check if your `img` tag's `src` is using request params or REST-style URLs. The latter will work better for caching by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a plugin called [Caching Headers](https://grails.org/plugin/cache-headers) for Grails which will handle all the needed caching and etag generation so that browsers won't request the download of the file when it's not modified and within your configured caching period.

It's pretty simple to use if you read through the documentation and take your time to test your configuration.

Comment: does it work with static images?
I'm trying to fix Image Expires Tag.
"Your site is not using expires headers for your images. An expires tag can help speed up the serving of your webpages for users that regularly visit your site and see the same images."